# How many employers work on each department?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Here are my tables:

```
SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENT;

    DEPTNO DNAME                LOC                                                                                     
---------- -------------------- --------------------                                                                    
        10 SWIFT WOLVER         WOLVERHAMPTON                                                                           
        20 SWIFT BIR            BIRMINGHAM                                                                              
        30 SWIFT MAN            MANCHESTER                                                                              
        40 SWIFT LON            LONDON                                                                                  


SELECT * FROM Employee;

     EMPNO ENAME      HIREDATE           SAL     DEPTNO                                                                 
---------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ----------                                                                 
      1039 KING       17-NOV-1980       5000         10                                                                 
      1066 JONES      02-APR-1991       2975         20                                                                 
      1088 SCOTT      23-AUG-2016       3000         20                                                                 
      1276 ADAMS      26-SEP-2016       1100         20                                                                 
      1002 FORD       03-DEC-1991       3000         20                                                                 
      1169 SMITH      17-DEC-1990        800         20                                                                 
      1098 BLAKE      01-MAY-1981       2850         30                                                                 
      1099 ALLEN      20-FEB-1995       1600         30                                                                 
      1221 WARD       22-FEB-1994       1250         30                                                                 
      1454 MARTIN     28-SEP-1993       1250         30                                                                 
      1544 TURNER     08-SEP-1981       1500         30                                                                 
      1300 JAMES      03-DEC-1981        950         30                                                                 
      1482 CLARK      09-JUN-1989       2450         10                                                                 
      1134 MILLER     23-JAN-1985       1300         10
```

I have primary key on `DEPTNO` (department table) and foreign key on `DEPTNO` (employee table).

I wrote this query that is supposed to list how many employers work on each department using `Group by` command, but something does not work. When I'm trying to run the query, something goes wrong on `COUNT`, but can't find what exactly. Can anyone help me with this?

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT.DNAME,COUNT(EMPLOYEE,DEPTNO) AS Numberofemployers FROM EMPLOYEE
LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENT
ON DEPARTMENT.DEPTNO = EMPLOYEE.DEPTNO
GROUP BY DEPARTMENTNAME;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

```
SELECT d.DNAME, COUNT(e.DEPTNO) AS Numberofemployees 
FROM DEPARTMENT d LEFT JOIN
     EMPLOYEE e
     ON d.DEPTNO = e.DEPTNO
GROUP BY d.DNAME;
```

Notes;

- You are aggregating by the department name, so I assume you want all departments.  Hence, `DEPARTMENT` should be the first table in the `LEFT JOIN`.
- You want to count the matching records in `EMPLOYEE`.  Hence the `COUNT(e.DEPTNO)`.
- `COUNT()` usually takes a single argument.  You have multiple arguments.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.